# Keeping duplicate values with idxmax in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data frame where I have two columns, `id` and `date`.

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[1, '2019-05-20'], [1, '2019-05-20'], [1, '2018-04-23'], [2, '2020-01-01'], [2, '2020-01-01'], [2, '2019-12-31']], columns=['id', 'date'])

   id   date
    1   2019-05-20
    1   2019-05-20
    1   2018-04-23
    2   2020-01-01
    2   2020-01-01
    2   2019-12-31
```

For each unique `id`, I want to select all rows that have the latest `date`. So my ideal solution should be as follows:

```
id  date
1   2019-05-20
1   2019-05-20
2   2020-01-01
2   2020-01-01
```

I implemented this by grouping the data frame by `id` and then using the `idxmax` function to select the latest date for each `id, as follows:

```
df[df.groupby('id').date.idxmax()]
```

However, this only gives me the first row for each unique `id` which has the latest `date`, so I end up getting the following result:

```
id  date
1   2019-05-20
2   2020-01-01
```

Is there a way that I can select all rows with the `idxmax` function that have the highest date value for each `id`? I saw on the pandas github repo that there was a PR that addressed this(https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/pull/35257), but this PR was closed and not approved.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: kindly share sample data with expected output

Comment: @sammywemmy ive added a reproducible example, thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `max` and self-merge:

```py
df.groupby('id', as_index=False).date.max().merge(df)
```

Output:

```
   id       date
0   1 2019-05-20
1   1 2019-05-20
2   2 2020-01-01
3   2 2020-01-01
```

---

Alternatively, you can set the index with repeated values per date, then use `idxmax`:

```py
df.index = df.groupby('date').ngroup()
df.loc[df.groupby('id').date.idxmax()]
```

Comment: Thank you. This answer was very helpful and crucial...